# How to print and Click all the child elements in list though Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have one Element "Sectors", when hover to Sector in drop down we have different child elements in list.
and i want to print all the elements in the list and also click all the element in Python.basically I want to make it dynamic so that in future if any child element is added r deleted so it wont effect my script.
I have written my selenium script but unable to print elements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains



element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_id("mnu_Sectors")
hover = selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()


list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#mnu_Sectors > ul > li")
for value in list:
 print(value)
 driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(value).click()
```

and in result am i getting this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/maham/PycharmProjects/Test/script.py", line 26, in <module>
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(value).click()
  File "C:\Users\maham\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 613, in find_elements_by_css_selector
    return self.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\maham\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 995, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "C:\Users\maham\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\maham\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.75)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The HTML code is

```html
<li id="mnu_Sectors" onmouseover="javascript:onMenuNavHover(this);" onmouseout="javascript:onMenuOnBlur();" class="fl-menu">
                    <a menu-item="javascript:void(0)" href="javascript:void(0)">Sectors
                            <i class="arrow"></i>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="holder-full" style="display: none;" onmouseover="javascript:onSubMenuNavHover();">
                            <li>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/bank/sectorid/4" href="/en/sector/bank/sectorid/4" class=""><i class="arrow "></i>Banks</a>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/cement/sectorid/6" href="/en/sector/cement/sectorid/6" class=""><i class="arrow "></i>Cement</a>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/petrochemicals/sectorid/33" href="/en/sector/petrochemicals/sectorid/33" class="lock-menu-icon"><i class="arrow lock-menu-icon"></i>Petrochemicals</a>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/insurance/sectorid/2/" href="/en/sector/insurance/sectorid/2/" class=""><i class="arrow "></i>Insurance</a>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/telecom/sectorid/52" href="/en/sector/telecom/sectorid/52" class=""><i class="arrow "></i>Telecom &amp; IT</a>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/healthcare/sectorid/218/true" href="/en/sector/healthcare/sectorid/218/true" class=""><i class="arrow "></i>Health Care</a>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/real-estate-development/sectorid/44/" href="/en/sector/real-estate-development/sectorid/44/" class=""><i class="arrow "></i>Real Estate Development</a>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/hotels-and-tourism/sectorid/36" href="/en/sector/hotels-and-tourism/sectorid/36" class=""><i class="arrow "></i>Hotels &amp; Tourism</a>
                                    <a menu-item="/en/sector/reits/sectorid/78" href="/en/sector/reits/sectorid/78" class=""><i class="arrow "></i>REITs</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you use `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("mnu_Sectors > ul > li")` - this returns a list of WebElement objects. You are then passing these WebElement(s) to `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(value).click()`, but a string is expected not a WebElement object ([as per the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)). This is where your error is coming from.
You could click all the elements by simply iterating over your list (assuming your css selector you are finding by is correct):

```
for value in list:
    value.click()
```

**Edit:**
Try getting your elements like so: `list = driver.find_element_by_class_name('holder-full').find_element_by_tag_name('li').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')`

Comment: half of my problem is solved, every time only one element from the list is selected  it is not taking element repeatedly.and every time that same element "Telecom" is selected

Comment: list = driver.find_element_by_class_name('holder-full').find_element_by_tag_name('li').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for value in list:
 value.click(). Still only one first child is selected. and error is : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/maham/PycharmProjects/Test/script.py", line 27, in <module>
    value.click()
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document